# Why is creating an instance of this object altering the instance variable of another object?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have defined a bankaccount class, and created two different accounts that extend bankaccount: savings account and checkings account. Their constructors I have posted below:

```
public class TimeDepositAccount extends SavingsAccount{
    private int numberOfMonths;
    private static final double WITHDRAW_PENALTY = 20;

    TimeDepositAccount(double interestRate, int numberOfMonths){
        super(interestRate);
        this.numberOfMonths = numberOfMonths;
    }
}
```

and savings account:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    private static double interestRate;

    public SavingsAccount(double interestRate){
        super();
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }


}
```

In my tester I create a savingsaccount, and then a timedeposit account:

```
SavingsAccount momsSavings = new SavingsAccount(5);
TimeDepositAccount collegeFund = new TimeDepositAccount(10, 3);
```

After going through the debugger, momsSavings' interest rate is set to 5 like i specified, however, when i create collegeFund, the program changes momsSavings' interest rate to 10, along with creating the collegeFund object. Could someone tell me where my error is?

Thank you.

Comment: `interestRate` isn't an instance variable, it's a static variable. Not a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared interestRate to be static, so there's only one value across all instances.

Change it to non-static:

```
 private double interestRate;
```

Comment: Oh wow. That was foolish of me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. If you consider this the best answer, you can click the checkmark to its side. You can also upvote multiple answers by clicking the up-triangle to its side.

Answer (score 2):

Static Variables are class members, and all instances of an object share the same information